# Problems to get jquery to work in json rendered html format

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I run a "strip out" version of FB bigPipe and it's working perfect, except the jquery. When I parse the jquery in json format and append to a div tag, the jquery stop working.

You can see the "bigPipe" jquery code I use  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YHVzE/1/)

The code to get this working is pretty simple. In PHP:

```
$data = array(
        'id' =>  {div tag ID},
        'content' => {html content},
        'title' => {document title},
        'css' =>  {...},
        'js' => {...}
        );

$output = '<script>Test.render(' . json_encode($data) . ');</script>';
```

I think the problem is that I have to add window.addEventListener not to the window itself, but to the div tag I append the content.

And here I'm stuck. How do I do this?  How do I get this jquery to work in this appended html?

**Here is a example on how it should work:**

If you try to run this code from a php file problems occur.Do this:

1. Put the js code from jsFiddle in a js file and include normaly in the .php file. Make a div tag in the php file and call it "not_working"- Save
2. Make a empty .html document and add a div tag like `<div
   id="test">Click me</div>` and save.

   1. Make a new js file and name it test.js.
      Put in this code:

$(function() {

```
$("body").on("click","#test",function(){
    alert("You clicked me!!");
});
```

});

Save.

1. In the PHP file, add this: `$data = array(
           'id' =>  "not_working",
           'content' => {LINK and NAME to the HTML file you created!!},
           'title' => "Test",
           'css' =>  "",
           'js' => {LINK and NAME to the JS file you created!!},
           );`
2. Run the .php file, click on the Click me!.

Comment: jquery? i dont see any jquery in the jsfiddle code? do you mean Javascript?

Comment: do you have some javascript errors? what is the result? can you give a bit more context?

Comment: @winner_joiner I updated my question with a tutorial on how this should work. Try it and tell me why not working :)

Comment: +1 for updating the question with extra info (even jsFiddle) and for posting self found solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was a error in the way the js files was inserted into the body element. After fixing that code. I solved it, and now everything work perfect.

If someone try to use this code, here is the changes:

```
function _addJsFile(filename) {
  var blody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
  script = document.createElement('script'),
  done = false;

  script.src = filename;
  script.type='text/javascript';
  script.onload = function() {
      if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState === "loaded" || this.readyState === "complete")) {
        done = true;
        // Handle memory leak in IE
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (blody && script.parentNode) {
          blody.removeChild(script);
        }
     }
  };

  blody.appendChild(script);
}
```